# Create a Spark Dataframe from a JSON section

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to get "data" content into a Spark DataFrame from following JSON structure:

```
{
  "meta" : {},
  "data" : [ 
    [ 1, "a1", "b1" ],
    [ 2, "a2", "b2" ],
    [ 3, "a3", "b3" ]
  ]
}
```

I am using Scala, but I can also use Spark SQL.

I am using this function:

```
def GetUrlContentJson(url: String): DataFrame ={
    val result = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString
    val jsonResponseOneLine = result.toString().stripLineEnd    
    val jsonRdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(jsonResponseOneLine :: Nil)
    val jsonDf = spark.read.json(spark.createDataset(jsonRdd))
    return jsonDf
}
```

However, the result is:

```
+-------+-------+
|   data|   meta|
+-------+-------+
| [[1...|     {}|
+-------+-------+
```

While I want is something similar to:

```
+----+------+------+
| id |   A  |   B  |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |   a1 |  b1  |
+----+------+------+
|  2 |   a2 |  b2  |
+----+------+------+
|  3 |   a3 |  b3  |
+----+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **`explode`** function then create new columns based on **`array`** size(3).

**`Example:`**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val str= """{
  "meta" : {},
  "data" : [ 
    [ 1, "a1", "b1" ],
    [ 2, "a2", "b2" ],
    [ 3, "a3", "b3" ]
  ]
}"""
//create dataset with the json string
val ds = spark.createDataset(str :: Nil)
//read the dataset as json
val df=spark.read.json(ds)
val explode_df = df.select(explode(col("data")))
explode_df.select((0 until 3).map(i => col("col")(i).alias(s"col$i")): _*).toDF("id","A","B").show(10,false)

//+---+---+---+
//|id |A  |B  |
//+---+---+---+
//|1  |a1 |b1 |
//|2  |a2 |b2 |
//|3  |a3 |b3 |
//+---+---+---+
```